# Set distinct notification tones for Slack apps

Tags: notifications, slack

Our application is hosted on Slack, where it sends alerts to workspace members. To ensure that these messages don't go unnoticed, we would like to set a unique notification tone for all alerts sent through our app. I noticed that Slack does not provide a direct option for this in their notification settings.
Is there a way to programmatically achieve this?